# WSO2 API synapse configuration issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm currently trying to solve one issue in wso2 API manager v1.9.
    I'm login to publisher and create an API i,e SampleAPI, in the design phase I have added 3 GET resources /sample1,/sample2 and /Sample3 respectively.
    and implement phase, provided a production endpoint e.g http://test/sample/1.0 and finally in the manage phase provided tier details and rest are all default setting, after that I saved and published the API.
    Then I'm login to Carbon console and modified the /sample2 and /sample3 resource endpoint to http://test/sample/45 and http://test/sample/46 respectively and saved the synapse configuration.

Upto this step is everything is ok, I have tested all the resources is working fine.

Later I have added another resource to the same API , so what I did, login to publisher and edit the SampleAPI and added another GET resource /sample4 and saved the configuration and again login to carbon console and try to add endpoint for /sample4 resource, then what I noticed, all the resources are reset to default endpoint, which I had provided during API configuration.

Could you please suggest how to handle this scenario? I want to keep all the configured endpoint details for each resources instead of reset to default endpoint even I add a new resource to the same API.